# Naming conventions in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

There are some things in redux that one has to remember for using it.
For creating a slice the keyword is reducers which is right as there can be many reducer functions
For exporting from the slice we use "slice.reducer". There is some type of mismatch here, which one mostly needs to remember before using it, as it has no definite logic as to why the names are like this. This impacts in the learning curve of redux.

I want this problem to be solved, it will make the one who uses redux to understand what he is doing behind the scenes. I made my own redux package, which almost works like the official, and have solved the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and clarify your question.

Comment: BTW, "one mostly needs to remember before using it" there is no need to memorise property names or create a custom package. You need to start using typescript with a proper IDE (VSCode, WebStorm, etc).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a mismatch.

`createSlice` takes multiple (case) `reducers` and puts all of them into one `reducer` function.
If you look at it, `slice.reducer` is not an object or array with multiple items (which would make sense with a plural) - it's a singular function.

Generally though: use an IDE with TypeScript support like Visual Studio Code. Even if you are just writing plain JavaScript, the editor will use the library types to tell you what is available and how the options are named. No reason to remember all that.